# How priority of Push Notifications is decided in Android or iOS apps?

Tags: android, ios

Suppose user has received around 5 notifications for the same app in Notification center/status bar and user tap any of the notification from notification center/status bar without viewing it then: What should the result be?

1. User should see the latest notification as an alert when the app opens?
2. User should see the first notification as an alert when the app opens?
3. User should see all notifications as alerts when the app opens?
4. User should see the notification I tapped on as an alert when the app opens?
5. Any other option?

Comment: This feels more like an usability questions then testing (but off-topic), I would ask it on: http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'd agree - @Subzero, we can ask to migrate this if you wish?

Comment: Yes, we can move this question to UX section.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are few good UX articles on mobile notifications:**

- [A Conversation with Gina Trapani: On Designing Meaningful Notifications](http://www.adaptivepath.com/ideas/a-conversation-with-gina-trapani-on-designing-meaningful-notifications-2/)
- [The Elements Of The Mobile User Experience](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/12/elements-mobile-user-experience/) (see Feedback subsection)
- [Mobile Notifications](http://avc.com/2011/03/mobile-notifications/)
- [Why iOS notifications are ruining my marriage (and UX solutions)](http://hackingui.com/design/why-ios-notifications-are-ruining-my-marriage/)

---

> And my opinion is:
>
> - When user taps on specific notification, he expects specific context (some related functionality within an app)
> - When user launches application, then application can show things he has missed
>   (all notifications content, e.g. in scrollable list as a some part of a screen)